# Starting app with all global variables zeroed

Tags: android-ndk

I'm writing an Android NDK app which consists of a large platform-independent core in C with a few lines of Java glue code based on the `android.app.NativeActivity` class. This is working really fine except one thing which is giving me headaches.

The problem is that Android apps do not really quit when calling `ANativeActivity_finish()` but instead they are just put into some sort of idle state and AFAIU they are only really killed when Android needs the resources.

This Android peculiarity is a huge problem for me because my C core uses lots of global variables and they aren't reset to 0 when my C core runs its shutdown code. Thus, when Android launches my app after it has been shutdown, all globals contain some random state from the last time my app was run instead of 0.

This isn't a problem at all on all the desktop systems supported by my program (Win32, Mac OS, Linux) because on those systems programs can really quit. But on Android this is fundamentally different. Yes, I know that global variables are bad and that I should reset them to 0 when finished with them but we're talking about a very large C core that has been in development for almost 20 years now so it would require a massive effort to clean this all up just for Android.

That's why I'd like to ask whether there is some way to force Android to always zero out all my globals just like when the app is started for the very first time.

I've already done some research and AFAICS the only way to do this would be to really kill my application using `android.os.Process.killProcess()` but this looks like a brute-force method. Isn't there any other way to always get zeroed globals when starting my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial zeroing is performed by the operating system -- the variable storage occupies newly-mapped pages.  There is no "zero out the stuff that needs zeroing" internal function to call.

You have two basic approaches:

1. Make the Android app work like it does on other platforms, and kill the app manually to force a reload.
2. Make your app work like Android, and don't act like it's shutting down completely when it gets paused.  In other words, don't ever run your shutdown code.  You still need to release significant resources when the app gets paused, but that should be less of a burden than tearing everything down.

How feasible approach #2 is depends on the nature of your code.

> Yes, I know that global variables are bad and that I should reset them to 0 when finished with them but

If you absolutely must use globals, create a single global structure and pile everything into it, so if you need to reset it or dump all the state in a debugger, it's easy to find everything.  It's not ideal, but it's far easier to manage than hunting for scattered globals and (heaven forfend) static locals.

Comment: Thanks, is there a definite answer on how to "properly" kill the app manually? I've done some research and there seem to be many different suggestions, e.g. `System.exit()`, `android.os.Process.killProcess()`, the new API 21 `finishAndRemoveTask()` and `finishAffinity()` but so far I haven't found the definite answer how to kill the app manually. I've tried System.exit() but this leads to some warning messages on LogCat ("Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred") and sometimes also a "WIN DEATH" warning which seems that it isn't such a good solution...

Comment: Remember that you don't need to kill the *app*, you need to kill the *process* in which it is running, because you need the system loader to effectively reset your global variables. If there were other apps running in the same process you'd have no choice but to kill those too. With that in mind, the `killProcess()` approach (which sends a SIGKILL, same as low-memory killer) is appropriate. The advantage of `System.exit()` is that it will execute any "on exit" handlers that have been registered, but that's not usually relevant on Android because apps aren't expected to exit.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It works although on exit I do sometimes get LogCat messages saying FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION from JavaBinder or CONSUMER CLOSED INPUT CHANNEL OR AN ERROR OCCURRED or ATTEMPTED TO UNREGISTER ALREADY UNREGISTERED INPUT CHANNEL from InputDispatcher. I presume that these are just because my app goes away suddenly because of killProcess() which Android doesn't expect?

Comment: Very likely. The system is designed to cope with apps that crash, so it shouldn't have a problem recovering. You may get fewer complaints if the process is killed from one of the near-death Activity callbacks, like `onDestroy()`.